# Series sum of $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to sum this series, for some $x$?

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2x^n$$

> Working on the hint supplied by one user to integrate the series twice, results in $\frac{x^2}2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x^2}2 \frac a{1-r}$. Now for say, $x=6/7$, one gets the expression as $\frac{18}7$. Now if I differentiate this twice one gets, $\frac{324}{7^3}$. But the answer as computed in Mathematica should be $343$.
>
> So where am  I going wrong?

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Integrate twice and use the formula for geometric series.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @sbp What part do you need help on?

Comment: I understand the right hand side. I can indeed compute it, by Integrating twice and using geometric series formula. But the left hand side contains $\int(\int y(x)dx)dx$. What to do with it?

Comment: @sbp What additional specificity do you need?  Have you tried to integrate term by term?

Comment: After evaluating the RHS, differentiate twice both sides.

Comment: I understand the hint, but shouldn't there be a restriction on the x-values for the hint to work ? Shouldn't there be some interval of convergence attached to it ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik The open interval of convergence doesn't change when you integrate or differentiate a power series. Which means that the radius can be calculate either in the original series or after integrating twice....

Comment: You are right. I wasn't thinking about that.